What taxes are there on contractor work from Germany to Canada?
I would like to work from Germany (being resident there, with a EU citizenship) as an independent contractor for a Canadian company. I am registered now as a German freelancer (as a consultant, therefore "Freiberufler"). As far as I know there is an agreement between Canada and Germany excluding double taxation, but I'm getting contradictory informations. Apart from paying my income tax (and possibly "Umsatzsteuer") in Germany, are there any other taxes I will have to pay in Canada, or that the Canadian partner will have to deduct?

The whole point of an independent contractor is that you are not an employee and the party paying for your services does not need to do anything else but pay your invoice. You are responsible for all taxes, social security, health insurance, days you want to take off, and other payments that may otherwise involve the employer. You are your own employer. This also means you will have to charge significanly higher rates than an employee, so you get the same net every month.
Please note that being an independent contractor requires that at some point in time you have more than one client. Not immediately, but if you claim to be independent and you are audited by the tax authorities and you work exclusively for a single client, your status of "independence" might be under review. Obviously not immediately, everyone starts with their first client, but expect questions after a few years.
It also requires that there is no-one at your client that can tell you what to do. If you have a boss or teamlead or other person that is weisungsbefugt ("authorised to issue instructions"), you are by definition not independent.
Those constraints are there to protect poorer workers who are very much dependent on their employers, from their employers forcing them to just declare themselves independent contractors and skip all labor laws that should protect them. Those audits will probably overlook your case, if you make good money. But the law is the law, technically you cannot work "independently" for exactly one client. Prepare to have at least a little smokescreen so the authorities have an excuse to let you continue. Maybe the invoices can go to a differently named sub-company next year. Or you have another client, however small they may be.
Whether there are super specialized Canadian laws on paying invoices from overseas, that seems to be something for your client to figure out. As far as I know, for a company, an invoice is an invoice. If you are shipping physical goods, there might be customs who want a word, but you said "consultant", so I would guess it's just consulting, no physical items.
My personal advice would be to get a tax consultant to help you with setting this up on your end. Yes, the form at the Finanzamt is easy enough to set up, but you don't want to work for a year only to find out you made a mistake and lost thousands of Euros because you missed a detail. Small details, like for example the fact that you can decide to not work on public holidays, but you won't get paid either, or that the 6 weeks of paid leave some employees have is not included, or sick leave not being paid when you are self-employed, can easily lead to you miscalculating how much you need to charge to come out even with a "normal" German employee.

Even if the OP were an employee, they would not be subject to Canadian income taxes, and whether the OP is subject to Canadian taxes seems to be the main point of this question, not whether the company is compliant with labor laws or employer taxes.
